# Running Ant macro from within Jacoco's coverage task

Tags: ant, jacoco, macrodef

My project is using Ant and it has several test suites. Since each suite is ran in a similar way, there is a macro defined:

```
<macrodef name="exec-tests">
    <attribute name="test-suite" />
    <element name="test-run" implicit="yes" />
    <sequential>
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="true" haltonerror="true" showoutput="true" outputtoformatters="true" fork="true" maxmemory="512m">
            <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xms512m" />
            <classpath refid="test.run.class.path" />
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
            <test name="@{test-suite}" todir="${test.build.results.dir}" />
        </junit>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

So there are several targets running different suites like this:

```
<target name="run-xxx-tests" depends="build-tests">
    <exec-tests test-suite="com.mycompany.XxxTestsSuite" />
</target>

<target name="run-yyy-tests" depends="build-tests">
    <exec-tests test-suite="com.mycompany.YyyTestsSuite" />
</target>
```

Now i also want to run a test suite with Jacoco coverage. So it would be nice to do this:

```
<target name="run-xxx-tests-with-coverage" depends="build-tests">
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${test.coverage.unit.file}">
        <exec-tests test-suite="com.mycompany.XxxTestsSuite" />
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>
```

However, Jacoco seems to not support macros within coverage tag, as i'm getting error:

```
Caused by: C:\Users\taavi\projects\cds\build.xml:87: exec-tests is not a valid child of the coverage task
    at org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask.addTask(CoverageTask.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:367)
```

For now i created another macrodef that is very similar to the "exec-tests" but just adds coverage. It is not critical, but i'm wondering is there any way to still avoid this duplicate "junit" task part?

k6ps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<jacoco:coverage>` task has [an `enabled` attribute](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) that may be useful...

> If set to true coverage data will be collected for the contained task.

To use `enabled`, you could make several changes to `<exec-tests>`:

- move `<jacoco:coverage>` into it
- add an optional `coverage.destfile` attribute

How it would look...

```xml
<macrodef name="exec-tests">
    <attribute name="test-suite" />
    <!-- If <test-suite> is called without coverage.destfile, then -->
    <!-- coverage.enabled won't be set to true and coverage info won't -->
    <!-- be collected.  -->
    <attribute name="coverage.destfile" default="" />
    <element name="test-run" implicit="yes" />
    <sequential>
        <local name="coverage.enabled" />
        <condition property="coverage.enabled" value="false" else="true">
            <equals arg1="@{coverage.destfile}" arg2="" />
        </condition>
        <jacoco:coverage enabled="${coverage.enabled}" destfile="@{coverage.destfile}">
            <junit ...>
            ...
            </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Then, each test could specify if coverage information should be collected...

```
<exec-tests
    test-suite="com.mycompany.XxxTestsSuite"
    coverage.destfile="${test.coverage.unit.file}" />
```

In the above example, coverage info will be collected because `coverage.destfile` is provided.

Comment: Yes, this idea worked for me. I even did not need the local tag, i just introduced a coverage-enabled property to the macrodef:  `<jacoco:coverage destfile="${test.coverage.unit.file}" enabled="@{coverage-enabled}">`